# How to move a plugin from dev to prod?

Tags: plugin-development, composer

I have a plugin that I developed in a symlinked folder locally.
I now want to deploy it to production.
But when I do `composer require namespace/pluginhandle` it gets symlinked.

What I want is to install it just like all the other production plugins - without a symlink.

I couldn't find instructions on how to do this in the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/plugin-guide.html#loading-your-plugin-into-a-craft-project).

Comment: Did you remove it from the `"repositories"` section in your `composer.json`? Also, did you publish it to Packagist?

Comment: @Oli I still have the `"repositories"` section pointing to my plugin dev folder. I'm not using Packagist. Should I just copy the entire folder into `/vendor` and then do a `composer update`?